# Clickevent triggering before viewModel can grab radio button values

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone view for some radio buttons that is essentially handling how to collect the data from the page the radio button is on and what to do if the radio button is clicked.

My problem is on certain pages (where the user deems it necessary to go to the next page when clicking the radio button, stupid I know, but is a requirement) the click event is being triggered before the viewmodel can gather the information on the radio button. Is there a way to trigger the view model to gather that info before the click event is triggered?

At the top I have my event

```
extendEvents: {
   'click .btn': 'getClickEventAction'
},
```

then I am creating my viewModel

```
 createViewModel: function() {
  var viewModel = kb.viewModel(this.model, {
            exclude: ['Options']
        });
  viewModel.value = WorkflowLayout.controlValue(viewModel); //function where I am finding the values and doing other fun stuff to them to make the rest of the app work.
},
```

and then my clickeventaction

```
getClickEventAction: function(event) {
   var $el = $(event.currentTarget);
   var action = $el.data('clickeventaction');
   var code = $el.data('clickeventcode');
   if (action && this[action]) this[action](code);
},
```